# Trouble creating dockerfile for Object Detection API Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, object-detection-api

As the title suggests, I'm trying to build this dockerfile. To add some context: I successfully pulled the official repository and adapted the model to my needs. Following the docs on github installing and running the model on my local machine is not a problem.

Now, to put this model into production I have to create a docker for the obvious reasons. First of all, the directory looks like this:

```
TFModels
    > Dockerfile
    > pycocotools
    > research
          > object_detection
    > slim
```

Now, the dockerfile which also encompasses the instructions from github concerning protoc, looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  unzip \
  protobuf-compiler \
  python-pil \
  python-lxml \
  python-tk

RUN mkdir -p /TFModel/
COPY research /TFModel/research
COPY slim /TFModel/slim

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r /TFModel/research/object_detection/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /TFModel/research

RUN protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
RUN export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

RUN python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py

RUN python object_detection/objectDetectImg.py
```

Building the docker gives following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "object_detection/objectDetectImg.py", line 24, in <module>
        from utils import label_map_util
      File "/TFModel/research/object_detection/utils/label_map_util.py", line 21, in <module>
        from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
    ImportError: No module named 'object_detection'
    The command '/bin/sh -c python object_detection/objectDetectImg.py' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I think the error may be in this line:

```
RUN export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Anyone who could help?
Thanks in advance